# How to fix “Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips'” error?

Tags: dvips

I am going to write a paper for "International Journal for Numerical Methods in Engineering", published by Wiley. I have downloaded the LATEX package from the website of the journal. It gives the above-mentioned error. Some people say that "do not use 'dvips' option". But this is the standard format of the journal and I think we cannot change this option. Could you please help me to solve this problem without making any significant change in the sample file of the journal?

Comment: use latex rather than pdflatex, then that option is what you need

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just ask that yournal, if they are expecting you to send a DVI or PDF. If they do not care, just delete this driver option from `hyperref`. This is far away from a "significant change in the sample".